# Find the value of $n$ for these circles.

Tags: geometry, circles

> Circle $B$, which has radius $2008$, is tangent to horizontal line $A$ at point $P$. Circle $C_1$ has radius $1$ and is tangent both to circle $B$ and to line $A$ at a point to the right of point $P$. Circle $C_2$ has radius larger than $1$ and is tangent to line $A$ and both circles $B$ and $C_1$. For $n > 1$, circle $C_n$ is tangent to line $A$ and both circles $B$ and $C_{n–1}$. Find the largest value of $n$ such that this sequence of circles can be constructed through circle $C_n$ where the $n$ circles are all tangent to line $A$ at points to the right of $P$.

[image]

I tried forming series of equations using Pythagoras theorem and the radii $r_i$ of the circles:

$r_2=r_1*\frac{2008+r_1}{2008-r_1}$ and $r_3=r_2*\frac{2008+r_2}{2008-r_2}$ etc.

but I'm not sure what the limiting case will for $n$ and how to use it for finding the last equation. Can someone suggest an alternate approach or a limiting case?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What were the radii of $C_2$ and $C_3$?

Comment: @Henry $r_2=r_1*\frac{2008+r_1}{2008-r_1}$,   $r_3=r_2*\frac{2008+r_2}{2008-r_2}$

Comment: This is a special case of the Apollonius packing theorem of successions of 4 circles. The 4th circle here is actually the horizontal that runs through $P$ with zero curvature. See https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-kissing which provides the formula for the relation between the curvatures (=inverse radii).

Comment: I suspect you should have $r_{i+1}= \left(r_i^{-1/2} -2008^{-1/2}\right)^{-2}$ at least while $0<r_1<2008$, though this might be easier to read as $a_{i+1}=a_i-a_0$ while $a_i>a_0$ where $a_i=\frac1{\sqrt{r_i}}$ and $a_0= \frac1{\sqrt{2008}}$.  That might suggest the answer might be something like ${\frac{a_1}{a_0}} =\sqrt{\frac{r_0}{r_1}}$ rounded up

Comment: @Henry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle this seems to support your comment but how did you derive it?

Comment: Ford circles plus [Descartes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) and @R.J.Mathar's link was what caused me to suspect that particular relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=2008$, $r_i$ is radius of $i$-th circle, $x_i$ is distance from $P$ to tangent point of $i$-th circle with line $A$.

Then from Pythagoras theorem:

$$\begin{aligned}
(R+r_i)^2=(R-r_i)^2+x_i^2 \\
(R+r_{i+1})^2=(R-r_{i+1})^2+x_{i+1}^2 \\
(r_i+r_{i+1})^2=(r_{i+1}-r_i)^2+(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2
\end{aligned}$$

Solving for $r_{i+1}$ in terms of $r_i$ gives

$$r_{i+1}=\frac{Rr_i}{\left(\sqrt{R}-\sqrt{r_i}\right)^2}$$

Last circle has radius greater than or equal to $R$. Sequential numerical calculation of all $r_i$ starting from $r_1=1$ gives that $r_{44}<R$, $r_{45} > R$. Then maximum $n$ is 45. Next circle may be tangent to $A$ at point to the left of $P$, but this is prohibited by problem statement.

[image]

Deleted after reading comments:

I don't know if there is simple way to check at what $i$ radius $r_i$ becomes greater than $R$.

Added after reading comments:

$$r_{i+1}=\frac{Rr_i}{\left(\sqrt{R}-\sqrt{r_i}\right)^2}\Rightarrow
\frac1{\sqrt{r_{i+1}}}=\frac{\sqrt{R}-\sqrt{r_i}}{\sqrt{Rr_i}}=
\frac1{\sqrt{r_i}}-\frac1{\sqrt{R}}$$
$$\frac1{\sqrt{r_n}}=\frac1{\sqrt{r_1}}-\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{R}}$$
$$r_n\geq R \Rightarrow \frac1{\sqrt{r_n}}\leq \frac1{\sqrt{R}}
\Rightarrow\frac1{\sqrt{r_1}}\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{R}} \Rightarrow
n\geq \sqrt{\frac{R}{r_1}}$$
$$n=\left\lceil \sqrt{\frac{R}{r_1}} \right\rceil=45$$

Comment: What is $x_i$ in your equations and what calculations did you perform to get $44$ and $45$?